# Arranging alphabets in a right angled triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, alphabetical

I want to arrange alphabets in a right-angle triangle. One example is:- inp='''1''' out=`_A_`, inp='''3''' out= `_A_\n_A_B_\n_A_B_C_` . This is what I have tried so far:-

```py
def letter_range(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        # inner loop
        for j in range(65, i + 1):
            print(f"_{chr(j)}_", end = "")
        print()

def main():

    x = int(input())
    y = int(65 + x)
    # calling Function
    letter_range(65, y)


     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#Results
inp = 3
out:-
_A_
_A__B_
_A__B__C_
```

I just want single underscores after and before each alphabet. Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
for j in range(65, i + 1):
        print(f"_{chr(j)}_", end = "")
    print()
```

with

```
for j in range(65, i + 1):
        print(f"_{chr(j)}", end = "")
    print('_')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `str.join`

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

def letters(n):
    return "_%s_" % "_".join(ascii_uppercase[:n])
```

Output:

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print(i, letters(i))

1 _A_
2 _A_B_
3 _A_B_C_
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do.
`string` module can be very helpful. `ascii_uppercase` contain all capital letters. So you can use indexing for string, then use `str.join()`

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print(f"_{'_'.join(ascii_uppercase[:i])}_")
```